# Color sprite tint with opacity in MonoGame/XNA

Tags: xna, monogame

In MonoGame I am using SpriteBatch to draw sprites. I want to create a semi transparent overlay that would 'tint' the sprite with a given color. `SpriteBatch.Draw` accepts `Color` parameter that allows to specify the tint, however the alpha channel seems to make the whole sprite transparent (not the tint only).

To address the problem i am overlaying my sprites with another white, semitransparent sprite tinted to a given color. It works as expected, but I am not sure if that is the correct (and most optimal) approach.

Can you suggest better/faster technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a color with alpha in the `SpriteBatch.Draw(...Color)`.  Your sprite's transparent parts will stay that way, and their opaque parts will be tinted.

Comment: sorry maybe I wasnt clear, my sprite is opaque (no transparency), its just when i use SpriteBatch.Draw with eg. Color.Green the tint is too strong, i would like it to be Color.Green with 30% opacity.

Comment: In that case, try using something that is almost white.  Like `Color(250,255,250)`

Comment: thanks! that's a correct answer. Now it seems obvious :)

Answer (score 1):

"Color.Green the tint is too strong, i would like it to be Color.Green with 30% opacity."

I think you mean [**saturation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), not opacity. Here you go:

```
Color desaturatedGreen = Color.Lerp(Color.White, Color.Green, 0.3f);
```